# invoke 'ctrl+v' command using python (pywinauto)

Tags: pywinauto

I am using python automation tool `pywinauto` in order to insert characters to some other application textbox.

The best way I have found to do this is to invoke `ctrl+v` after I have copied the text I want to insert to the clipboard and have set focus to the other application window.

How can I invoke `ctrl+v` command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
app.MainWindow.Edit.TypeKeys(r'^v')
```